# Select multiple options in WordPress custom meta filed

Tags: custom-field

I have added select box using meta box in post. I try to select multiple options in select box but did't save multiple option in post meta. Only select last selected option.

how to save multiple selected options in post meta? Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you have used select box name attribute as an array.

```
Example: <select name="data[]" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Please try above code and let me know if still problem persists.

Comment: Thanks, but not working. Saved only last selected value not all selected values.

Comment: Can you please paste you code so that i can trace you issue and help you out?